# Existence of totally real number fields of any degree

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, analytic-number-theory, class-field-theory

Are there simple/canonical examples for totally real number fields of degree $n$ for any natural number $n \in \mathbb{N}$? Of course, the question can be reformulated by asking if there exists an irreducible polynomial of degree $n$ with real roots only, i.e. all roots in the algebraic closure $\mathbb{C}$ are real.

Currently, I just started to read about field theory, but in the standard books (and soucres) I could not find an answer to my question.

- $\mathbb{Q}(\cos(2\pi/n))$ is an example of degree $\varphi(n)/2$.
- In the Paper [On 2-Rank of the Ideal Class Groups of Totally Real Number Fields](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pja/1195515930) of Ichimura one can find a construction of such polynomials (with some additional properties), using Hilbert's Irreducibility Theorem.

My question arose from Geometry of Numbers/Analytic Number Theory: Any totally real number field gives rise for an 'admissible lattice' $\Lambda$, that means $\inf_{(m_1,\ldots,m_n) \in \Lambda \setminus \{0\}} |m_1 \cdots m_d| >0$ in standard coordinates, as follows. Under the map $\mathbb{K} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$, $x \mapsto (\sigma_1(x),\ldots,\sigma_n(n))$, where $\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_n$ denote all embeddings (which are real since $\mathbb{K}$ is totally real) of the number field $\mathbb{K}$, the image of the ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{K}}$ is an admissible lattice.

Skriganov has shown in [Constructions of Uniform Distributions in Terms of Geometry of Numbers, 1994,](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=aa&paperid=459&option_lang=eng) that 'admissible lattices' are very uniformly distributed in parallelepipeds. (The remainder term is only of type $\log^{d-1}{r}$.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $p\equiv1\pmod{2n}$ be prime (existence guaranteed by a weak form
of Dirichlet's theorem). The field $\Bbb Q(\cos(2\pi/p))$ has degree
$\frac12(p-1)$ and is cyclic over $\Bbb Q$. So it has a degree $n$ subextension. This is totally real (and also cyclic over $\Bbb Q$).

Comment: I was looking for an example like that - thanks for your answer!  My missing point was that every subfield of a totally real subfield is also totally real. (Let $\mathbb{F} \subset \mathbb{K}$ be a subfield. Any embedding $\sigma \colon \mathbb{F} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ can be extended (by the Isomorphism extension theorem) to an embedding $\tilde{\sigma} \colon \mathbb{K} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$. Thus, if $\mathbb{K}$ is totally real, then also  $\mathbb{F}$.)